# beginner question, calling a function/assign property etc... of an object inside an array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, oop

So if I create an object test, and it has a property color. When I add this object to an array list I typically can access this using myarray(0).color but intellisense doesn't 'know' that I have a 'test' object inside the array. It would let me type myarray(0).whatever but would then crash if I made typo. It seems like I should be able to let it know what type of object I am trying to work with inside the arraylist.

In code maybe something like this

```
dim testobject as new test
testobject.color = "red"
dim testarray as new arraylist
testarray.add(testobject)

testarray(0).color = "blue"
```

Could someone tell me the name of this concept, and a more correct(if there is one) of how I should be doing this?

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead

```
dim a as System.collections.generic.List(of test) 
a(0).asf  ' Errror
```

Comment: great! Is this the concept loosly typed versus strongly typed?

Comment: Exactly Generics are strongly typed